# PayPal API - PHP Error Sending Payment

Tags: php, paypal

I am working on an ecommerce site that utizlizes PayPal's API. I am currently receiving the following error:

```
Error Sending Payment! exception 'PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException' with message 'Got Http response code 400 when accessing https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment.' in C:\xampp\htdocs\leisurelydiversion\vendor\paypal\rest-api-sdk-php\lib\PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection.php:178 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\leisurelydiversion\vendor\paypal\rest-api-sdk-php\lib\PayPal\Transport\PayPalRestCall.php(74): PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection->execute('{"intent":"sale...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\leisurelydiversion\vendor\paypal\rest-api-sdk-php\lib\PayPal\Common\PayPalResourceModel.php(102): PayPal\Transport\PayPalRestCall->execute(Array, '/v1/payments/pa...', 'POST', '{"intent":"sale...', NULL) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\leisurelydiversion\vendor\paypal\rest-api-sdk-php\lib\PayPal\Api\Payment.php(579): PayPal\Common\PayPalResourceModel::executeCall('/v1/payments/pa...', 'POST', '{"intent":"sale...', NULL, Object(PayPal\Rest\ApiContext), NULL) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\leisurelydiversion\cart.php(65): PayPal\Api\Payment->create(Object(PayPal\Rest\ApiContext)) #4 {main}
```

At first glance (to me anyway), it would seem that there was an issue connecting to the PayPal website. However, there are two reasons to believe the fault lies within my code. First, this issue occurs only when I have more than one item in my 'cart'. Secondly, it works just fine if I do not call the setItemList() method on the transaction object. This implies that there is a problem within the foreach statement used to populate $itemsArray; however, I have called var_dump on the array and all seemed fine.

```
array(2) { [0]=> object(PayPal\Api\Item)#6 (1) { ["_propMap":"PayPal\Common\PayPalModel":private]=> array(4) { ["name"]=> string(2) "22" ["currency"]=> string(3) "USD" ["quantity"]=> int(1) ["price"]=> string(5) "19.99" } } [1]=> object(PayPal\Api\Item)#5 (1) { ["_propMap":"PayPal\Common\PayPalModel":private]=> array(4) { ["name"]=> string(2) "21" ["currency"]=> string(3) "USD" ["quantity"]=> int(1) ["price"]=> string(5) "13.99" } } }
```

What might the issue be? Thanks so much for any help.

The main page:

```
`<?php
include("header.php");
require __DIR__ . '/bootstrap.php';

use PayPal\Api\Amount;
use PayPal\Api\Details;
use PayPal\Api\Item;
use PayPal\Api\ItemList;
use PayPal\Api\Payer;
use PayPal\Api\Payment;
use PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls;
use PayPal\Api\Transaction;

$cart = new cart();
if(isset($_GET['remove'])) {

$id = $_GET['remove'];

$cart->removeItem($id);
}

$subtotal = $cart->getSubtotal();
$total = $cart->getTotal();
$discount = $cart->getDiscount();
$count = $cart->getItemCount();
$merchandiseTotal = $subtotal - $discount;
$total = $merchandiseTotal + SHIPPING;

$payer = new Payer();
$payer->setPaymentMethod("paypal");

$itemsArray = array();

foreach($cart->items as $cartItem) {
$item = new Item();
$item->setName($cartItem->id)->setCurrency("USD")->setQuantity(1)->setPrice($cartItem->price);
$itemsArray[count($itemsArray)] =  $item;
}

var_dump($itemsArray);

$itemList = new itemList();
$itemList->setItems($itemsArray);

$details = new Details();
$details->setShipping(SHIPPING)->setSubtotal($merchandiseTotal);

$amount = new Amount();
$amount->setCurrency("USD")->setDetails($details);
$amount->setTotal($total);

$transaction = new Transaction();
$transaction->setAmount($amount)->setItemList($itemList)->setDescription("Purchase from Leisurely Diversion")->setInvoiceNumber(uniqid());

$redirectURLs = new RedirectUrls();
$redirectURLs->setReturnUrl("http://localhost/leisurelydiversion/confirmation.php?success=true")->setCancelUrl("http://localhost/leisurelydiversion/confirmation.php");

$payment = new Payment();
$payment->setIntent("sale")->setPayer($payer)->setTransactions(array($transaction))->setRedirectUrls($redirectURLs);





try {
$payment->create($apiContext);
} catch(Exception $e) {
echo "<h2> Error Sending Payment! $e</h2>";
}

$request = clone $payment;
$url = $payment->getApprovalLink() . "&useraction=commit";



?>

<table class='table table-striped table-responsive'>
<thead>
<tr>
<td>Item</td>
<td>Price</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tbody>
<?php if($cart->getItemCount() <= 0) {

echo " <tr>Your cart is empty!</tr>"; } else { foreach($cart->items as $item) {
echo "<tr><td>$item->name <a href='cart.php?remove=$item->id'>Remove from cart</a></td><td>$item->price</td></td>";
}
echo "<tr></tr><tr></tr><tr><td>Subtotal: </td><td>" . $subtotal . "</td> </tr>
<tr> <td>Discount: </td> <td>" . $discount . "</td> </tr>
<tr> <td>Shipping: </td> <td>" . SHIPPING . " </td></tr>
<tr> <td>Total: </td> <td>" . $total . "</td>";
}
?>
</tbody>
</thead>
</table>

<a href="<?php echo $url; ?>"><img src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/btn/btn_checkout_pp_142x27.png"/></a>
<?php
include("footer.php");
?>
```

The cart class

```
class cart {

public $items = array();


function __construct() {
$pdo = new pdoAccess("localhost","root","");
$counter = 0;
if (isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {  foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $item) {
$this->items[$counter] = $pdo->getItemDetails($item, "stock");
$counter++;
}
}
}

public function emptyCart() {
session_unset();
session_destroy();
}

public function removeItem($itemID) {
$index = array_search($itemID, $_SESSION['cart']);
unset($_SESSION['cart'][$index]);
$this->__construct();
}

public function getItemCount() {
if(isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
return count($_SESSION['cart']);
} else {
return 0;
}
}

public function getSubtotal() {
$total = 0;

foreach($this->items as $item) {

$total += $item->price;
}

return $total;

}

public function getDiscount() {
$sub = $this->getSubtotal();
if($this->getItemCount() >= 2) {
$discount = $sub * .1;
} else {
$discount = 0;
}
return round($discount, 2);
}

public function getTotal() {
$sub = $this->getSubtotal();

if($this->getItemCount() >= 2) {
$sub +- $this->getDiscount();
}

$total = $sub + SHIPPING;
return $total;


}
}
?>
```

And yes, I do have error-reporting on. The only warning I receive is as follows:

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\leisurelydiversion\vendor\paypal\rest-api-sdk-php\lib\PayPal\Common\PayPalResourceModel.php on line 44
```

I presume this is merely because the payment was not successfully sent as I believe the foreach() it refers to is responsible for returning the link used to complete the payment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to catch PayPalConnectionException as shown [in our wiki](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/wiki/exception-%27PayPal%5CException%5CPayPalConnectionException%27-with-message-%27Got-Http-response-code-400-when-accessing):

```
try {
    $payment->create($apiContext);
} catch (PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException $ex) {
    echo $ex->getCode(); // Prints the Error Code
    echo $ex->getData(); // Prints the detailed error message 
    die($ex);
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    die($ex);
}
```

Also, you are trying to get the approval link, even if it fails. You may need to exit the code after that, or move the approval link check inside the try catch method.

Comment: Thank you so much. As it turns out, the issue was with the total. I added a discount for multiple item purchases, but applied this to the purchase as a whole rather than each individual item. This resulted in some mismatch between the price of the itemList and details subtotal.